Why is QDA of scikit-learn warning me "Variables are Collinear" - what can i do about it?
In running QuadraticDiscriminationAnalysis (QDA) and .fit in the training, then calling the .predict to make prediction of a multinomial classification I'm getting the warning:

discriminant_analysis.py:935: UserWarning: Variables are collinear warnings.warn("Variables are collinear")

Following this, the program does not crash, but results in very poor classification, typically 20% when many other classifiers from scikit-learn are giving me 80 % to 90 % accuracy for the same dataset, including that of LDA.
From previous answers to quesions in this forum, I realise that such a warning happens when it considers the X-matrix to be linearly dependent, i.e. at least one of its vectors can be generated by a linear combination of the others. Under these circumstances the errors arising from the matrix inversion of the algorithms are large - I'm assuming this is why the classification accuracy is so poor.
However, I know for a fact that the X-matrix is not linearly dependent. So I'm assuming it fails perhaps because the X-matrix is close to linearly dependent, and under these conditions inversion of the matrix is not precise.
Assuming this is the problem, is there a better method of getting the X-matrix inversion, so the resulting errors of smaller and the classification accuracy higher?
(also since LDA generates good accuracy from the same dataset (i.e. X-matrix) the matrix inversion in this routine is fine - so why does it fail in QDA?)
I'm using scikit-learn version 1.3.0, Python 3.8 and the Anaconda package manager. Changing to scikit-learn 1.2.0 generates the same warning.
I tried running the program a number of times and I always got this result.
